# How can I use git-tfs when the repository requires code analysis before checkin?

Tags: git-tfs

I'm using [git-tfs](https://github.com/spraints/git-tfs), and trying to use `git tfs checkintool` to commit my Git changes to TFS. It brings up the TFS commit window, and I fill in my commit comment and associate my work items; but when I click OK, it gives me the "Policy Failure - Checkin cannot proceed because the policy requirements have not been satisfied" dialog. Here's the description of the policy warning:

> Internal error in Code Analysis. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.Sdk.UI, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Screenshot:

[image]

Not surprisingly, it gives this same DLL-not-found error regardless of whether or not I've already built and run code analysis in Visual Studio.

I found Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.Sdk.UI.dll in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies, and just for fun, I tried temporarily adding that directory to my PATH (from the command line: `set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\...`) and then running `git tfs checkintool` again. But it just gave the same error again when I clicked OK.

I can override the policy failure and commit, but I'd rather not do that every time I check in. I could also disable the code analysis policy entirely, but that hardly seems justified.

Is there a way I can make `git tfs checkintool` able to find this DLL so it can commit successfully?

Comment: Same problem here - any update from Joe or anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the same question was filed as an issue on the git-tfs site in github and got some further research there, but still no final resolution:

https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/82

It appears to be a bug in TFS.